# How could I insert new data to array without key in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an existing array that I created locally and import to Firebase and my array looks like this.

[image]

These both elements are objects created that have some many information related to appointments.

Now i am trying to create a new element with the same form, for example:

2--
  |__  And the object I have created in my app

I have only managed or eliminate the rest of the elements (with setValue(object))

```
        Appointment newAppointment = new Appointment.Builder()
            .fechacita(dateSelected)
            .horacita(hourSelected)
            .usertoken(mAuthManager.getCurrentUserId())
            .oficina(centerSelected)
            .build();

    mDatabaseRef.child("LISTACITAS").setValue(newAppointment);
```

or create it with an ID that when recovering the data causes a crash in the application due to the deserialization of the objects that are not equal.

The Appointment object that I want to insert is

```
public class Appointment implements Parcelable {

private String fechacita;
private String horacita;
private Office oficina;
private String userID;
.....
}
```

The class is a normal Parcelable class that generates an object with her builder.

Please some help...

Comment: Realtime Database can't automatically know what number is next in the array-like structure you've created.  You should use push() to generate a new key, and use child properties to figure out how each child is ordered relative to each other.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787817/how-to-add-a-user-to-a-firebase-numbered-array/50788095#50788095

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
mDatabaseRef.push().setValue(incidentReportUser)
```

Write it this way (`push()` adds values instead of overriding).

Ans from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408326/android-firebase-save-new-data-without-overwriting-old-data?answertab=active#tab-top)

**UPDATE 1**

if you want a series in key, not some random value, try this:

get the last key in the list using

```
Query dbQry = mDatabaseRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
dbQry.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       int key = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.getKey());

       //Increment the key and add the object here using the earlier method
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
}
```

I have not checked this as of now, but you could get the idea

Comment: I tried this too but this solution generates a key that I don't want to generate. Possibly it cant be possible to do that but I am not sure. The way I want to do is as the same form as the image I post, without a key generated by Firebase and creating an object with the "key" 2, following the other objects